# Are scuba diving questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Except when practising/training in a pool, scuba diving is done outdoors, and so would seem to fall under an "outdoors activity". Would questions on it therefore count as on-topic?

(I'm aware of the [scuba diving Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54313/scuba-diving), and [Travel.SE diving questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diving) which tend to be more about where to go than how to do it. There's also a [handful on the Sports beta](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scuba-diving), I'm just trying to work out if they'd also be on-topic here or not)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, scuba diving is on-topic. Ask away.

Comment: Would this then include snorkelling and free diving?

Comment: Definitely. If anything, snorkeling and free diving would be more on-topic.